# Как добавить кнопку в Discord Rich Presence?

Tags: python, discord

Хочу добавить кнопку с ссылкой в свой Discord Rich Presence, но не могу найти как именно это сделать. Вот такой код имею на данный момент:

```
def run():
try:
    rpc_obj = rpc.DiscordIpcClient.for_platform(app_id)
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=config['VK']['app_token'])
    vk = vk_session.get_api()

    print("Приложение было проинициализировано. Запуск.")
    while True:
        activity = {
            "assets": {
                "large_image": "favicon",
                #"show_join_button": True
            }
        }
        res = vk.users.get(user_ids=config['VK']['id'], fields="status")[0]

        if "status_audio" not in res:
            state = "Idle"
            if "details" in activity:
                activity.pop("details")

            activity.update({'state': state})
        else:
            curr_music = res['status_audio']
            state = f"{curr_music['artist']} - {curr_music['title']}"
            details = f"Слушает музыку"
            activity.update({'state': state, 'details': details})

        rpc_obj.set_activity(activity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Задался тем же вопросом, с похожим кодом
Кнопки удалось добавить только с помощью создания приложения в discord

код такой:

```
from pypresence import Presence
from time import time
RPC = Presence("client_id приложения")
btns = [
    {
        "label": "название кнопки",
        "url": "ссылка"
    },
    {
        "label": "название кнопки",
        "url": "ссылка"
    }
]
RPC.connect()
RPC.update(
    state="1 строка статуса",
    details="2 строка",
    start=time(), #(таймер работы)
    buttons=btns, #вызов кнопок
    large_image="название картики", #картинки загруженной в приложение
    
    large_text="текст" #текст картинки
)
input()
```

Соответственно если запустить этот код в discord то rich presence будет занят им.
Ответьте мне, пожалуйста, если вы нашли решение.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).